# QLocalServer won't start an incoming connection

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork, qt-signals, qlocalserver

I am creating a simple QSocketServer in Qt.  The socket starts to listen, but the incomingConnection method never seems to run.  Can someone explain what is wrong here?

#### main:

```
m_pipeserver = new PipeServer(this);  
if (m_pipeserver->listen("test.sock")) { 
    qDebug() << "STARTED";
}
```

#### pipeserver.h

```
class PipeServer : public QLocalServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PipeServer(Controller *parent = 0);
protected:
    void incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor);
```

#### pipeserver.cpp

```
PipeServer::PipeServer(Controller *parent) 
{
}
void PipeServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    qDebug() << "NEW CONNECTION";
    // etc...
```

I see the STARTED message, but never see the NEW CONNECTION when I run:

> socat -v READLINE unix-connect:/tmp/test.sock

Can anyone tell me why the incomingConnection is not firing?

--
UPDATE: Just for fun I hooked a method into the newConnection signal and that method DOES fire when I connect.  So why isn't the incomingConnection method firing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why the incomingConnection is not firing?

Michelle, it seems you have made a typo. The signature of the aforementioned virtual protected method can be read [in here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlocalserver.html#incomingConnection). There is a slight difference between the argument of that and your variant.

The fix would be to modify the declaration and definition in your corresponding header and sources as follows:

```
void incomingConnection(quintptr socketDescriptor);
//                       ^
```

I would suggest to start using the `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` macro as follows:

```
void incomingConnection(q**u**intptr socketDescriptor) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
```

This will make sure that you can get a compiler error when your Qt application is built with C++11 support, and when it is not, it will compile fine, too, but without giving an error. It is using the "override" context specifier introduced in C++11.